# HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded

Tags: ssl, python-requests

I've got a django app in production running on nginx/uwsgi. We recently started using SSL for all our connections. Since moving to SSL, I often get the following message:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='foobar.com', port=443): 
    Max retries exceeded with url: /foo/bar
```

Essentially what happens is I've got the browser communicating with django server code, which then uses the requests library to call an api. Its the connection to the api that generates the error. Also, I've moved all our requests into one session (a requests session, that is), but this hasn't helped.

I've bumped up the number of uwsgi listeners since I thought that could be the problem, but our load isn't that high. Also, we never had this problem before SSL. Does anyone have some advice as to how to solve this problem?

**Edit**

Code snippet of how I call the API. I've posted it (mostly) verbatim. Note its not the code that actually fails, but the requests library that throws an exception when calling `self.session.post`

```
def save_answer(self):
    logger.info("Saving answer to question")
    url = "%s1.0/exam/learneranswer/" % self.api_url
    response = {'success': False}

    data = {'questionorder': self.request.POST.get('questionorder'),
            'paper': self.request.POST.get('paper')}
    data['answer'] = ",".join(self.request.POST.getlist('answer'))
    r = self.session.post(url, data=simplejson.dumps(data))
    if r.status_code == 201:
        logger.info("Answer saved successfully")
        response['success'] = True
    elif r.status_code == 400:
        if r.text == "Paper expired":
            logger.warning("Timer has expired")
            response['message'] = 'Your time has run out'
        if r.text == "Question locked":
            response['message'] = \
                'This question is locked and cannot be answered anymore'
        else:
            logger.error("Unknown error")
            self.log_error(r, "Unknown Error while saving answer")
    else:
        logger.error("Internal error")
        self.log_error(r, "Internal error in api while saving answer")
    return simplejson.dumps(response)
```

Comment: Show us your requests code and nginx configuration. In fact, you can try setup a static html and have nginx points to it, use requests to display it in order to verify this is something to do with nginx, not django.

Comment: The problem isn't localised to a specific area of code. It happens at various portions. Mostly in one section because its the most used, but sometimes in other sections too. I've updated my question to include a snippet of code.

Comment: Did the request actually make to the views? Did it pass through nginx? Did nginx hand the request over to Django instance? Is the url working? To me, these are important questions to ask. That error can be misleading and may not actually provide why it's failing. Also, the 3rd line ``url = "1.0/exam/learneranswer/" % self.api_url`` you should have a placeholder in the string shouldn't it?

Comment: I fixed the placeholder. As I mentioned, the code works mostly. I recon it fails 2% of the time, and I'm not sure when or why. I'm also not sure if failed request goes through nginx. I'll check the serverlogs to see if I find something corresponding to the error.

Comment: What version of requests are you using? If not 1.2.0, please upgrade?

Comment: thanks sigmavirus24. I've upgraded and will deploy to prod this avi and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 16):

I've found that this error happens when some item in one of my views throws an exception.  For example, when using the django 'requests' framework to post data to another URL:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, timeout=5)
```

The downrange server was having connection issues, which threw an exception and that bubbled up and gave me the error you had above. I replaced with this:

```
try:
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, timeout=5)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    r = "No response"
```

And that fixed it (of course, I'd suggest adding in more error handling, but the above is the relevant subset).

Answer (score 9):

You must disable validation like this

```
requests.get('https://google.com', verify=False)
```

You should specify your CA.

Comment: The error in the question did not describe a certificate validation error, and recommending `verify=False` without any other constraints is dangerous because it allows a MITM attacker to masquerade as the remote server.

Comment: this answer doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurs as a result of python script trying to connect to IBM service even before your wifi or ethernet connection is established. Have a try/catch to rectify or if trying to run as service then run service after network is established.