# Python Requests requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:727: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run a code that gets data using xml requests. The host uses ssl, I tried adding verify=True but I get an SSL error. Python Requests requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:727: EOF occurred in violation of protocol. I use python 2.7

```
import argparse
import requests
import string



_xml = " ..."
host = ""
port = 0
_dictionary = string.digits + string.uppercase + string.lowercase

def _get_timeout(_data):
    return requests.post("http://{0}:{1}/testing/test".format(host, port),
                         headers={
                             "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 "
                                           "Firefox/57.0",
                             "SOAPAction": "",
                             "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
                         }, verify=True,
                         data=_xml.format(_data)).elapsed.total_seconds()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--host')
    parser.add_argument('--port')
    parser.add_argument('-v')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args_dict = vars(args)

    host = args_dict['host']
    port = args_dict['port']

    print "this may take a few minutes"
    for i in range(24):  
        for _char in _dictionary:
            if not (args_dict['v'] is None):
                print "checking {0}".format(_hash + _char)
            if _get_timeout(_hash + _char) > 1.300:  # timeout for local server
                _hash += _char
                print "Found " + _hash
                break
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 141, in <module>
    if _get_timeout(_hash + _char) > 1.300:  # timeout for local server
  File "test.py", line 119, in _get_timeout
    data=_xml.format(_data)).elapsed.total_seconds()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='..', port=..): Max retries exceeded with url: /testing/test (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:727)'),))
```

Comment: May be this post help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230850/httpsconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded

Comment: The server closed the connection. This has nothing to do with client side certificate validation so enabling or disabling it will not help. There can be many reasons for this, like the server not speak HTTPS in the first place, server requiring client certificate, unsupported cipher or protocol ... The way to fix the problem depends on the cause of the problem, which cannot be determined from the provided information.

Comment: its that server requires client certificate @SteffenUllrich

Comment: *"its that server requires client certificate"* - but you don't provide any client certificates in your code. If mutual authentication is used then you have to actually provide client certificates which are acceptable to the server, i.e. you cannot just make up something. So if you don't have such certificate and private key you cannot access the site.