# requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool on Replit.com,

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am running a simple code on the Replit.com, but I get an error. This code worked a week ago, but it doesn’t work now. The URL is accessible and works from the browser without problems. Searching for solutions on the Internet did not lead to results. How can I fix the error below?

```
import requests

url = ‘https://iss.moex.com/iss/statistics/engines/stock/markets/index/analytics.csv’
print(url)

r = requests.get(url).text
print (r)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):… requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host=‘iss.moex.com’, port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url:
> /iss/statistics/engines/stock/markets/index/analytics.csv (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, ‘[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF
> occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)’)))

I tried the solution from here
[HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230850/httpsconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded)
there is no result